# How can I increase connection timeout of SQL connectionstring?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, sql-server

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string filepath = textBox2.Text;
    string connectionString_i = string.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0; Data Source={0};Extended Properties=""Text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited""",
Path.GetDirectoryName(filepath));

    using (OleDbConnection connection_i = new OleDbConnection(connectionString_i))
    {
        connection_i.Open();

        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("Select * FROM [" + Path.GetFileName(filepath) +"]", connection_i);

        using (OleDbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            string sqlConnectionString = MyConString;

            using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnectionString))
            {
                SqlBulkCopy bulkInsert = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnectionString);
                bulkInsert.DestinationTableName = "Table in SQL DB";
                bulkInsert.WriteToServer(dr);
                MessageBox.Show("Upload to DB Successful!");
            }
        }
        connection_i.Close();
    }
}
```

Now I want to read file with large data and insert into SQL Table. the problem is that SQL connetion timeout is just 30 seconds.
I want to increase timeout of SQL connection to about 2 or 3 minutes.

How do I do that.. Please help.
I am uploading data from a csv file to SQL db.

Thanks.

Comment: It seems that this is 'not' about more time is needed but connection itself has problem. Try to close the reader before bulk command.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the `SqlBulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout` property. It defaults to 30 seconds. You additionally can increase the `OleDbCommand.CommandTimeout` of your SELECT command.

```
//set command timeout
 OleDbCommand command = 
     new OleDbCommand("Select * FROM [" + Path.GetFileName(filepath) +"]", connection_i);
 // 3 min
 command.CommandTimeout = 180;


 SqlBulkCopy bulkInsert = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnectionString);
 bulkInsert.BulkCopyTimeout = 180; // 3 min
 bulkInsert.DestinationTableName = "Table in SQL DB";
 bulkInsert.WriteToServer(dr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Aside from setting the connection timeout in your CONNECTION STRING, there is ALSO a timeout based on the actual SqlCommand.  So you could have a connection timeout of 3 minutes, but if your SqlCommand has a default timeout of 30 seconds, your command would time-out first.  You probably want to set BOTH